# WordPress - PHP Warning failed to open stream: No such file or directory (advanced-cache.php)

Tags: php, wordpress, caching, warnings

I'm getting this PHP Warning on back-end and front-end pages (WordPress) and can't figure out how to fix it:

> Warning: include(/home/.../public_html/wp-content/advanced-cache.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/.../public_html/wp-settings.php on line 84
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/home/.../public_html/wp-content/advanced-cache.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/.../public_html/wp-settings.php on line 84

Indeed, there is no advanced-cache.php in that directory (not sure if ever was), but absolutely the same configuration works on a different server without warnings.

Will appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you have installed `Advance cache plugin`, and a setting `WP_CACHE`

```
define('WP_CACHE', true);
// or may be it is a file like, if so then comment this line,
// below is the statement which need to be commented
// define('WP_CACHE', is_file(__DIR__.'/wp-content/advanced-cache.php'));
```

to prevent this error you can set to false, like

```
define('WP_CACHE', false);
```

Comment: Thank you, it helped. It was WP Super Cache and I did have define('WP_CACHE', false) in config.

Comment: "If your car makes a funny noise, don't use it"

Answer (score 5):

../wp-content/advanced-cache.php is generated dynamically when any caching plugin gets installed, especially caching plugins from wordpress.org use that. So you will not be able to find that file on fresh WP installation.

Please refer [link](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wp-contentadvanced-cache-php-frequently-changed/)

In your case, I assume that you have installed some caching plugin and due to any reason advanced-cache.php file is deleted from folder or there may be permission issue for executing the file. That's why when your caching plugin tries to search and include advanced-cache.php file than it cannot find it or execute it and this throws the error you mentioned.

For further possibilities and suggestions, I need to know which caching plugin do you use. Let me know if you want me to help further...

Comment: It's WP Super Cache. I solved the issue disabling define('WP_CACHE', false);. Thank you in any case.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the WP-CACHE to false on the wp-config file, you may also need to rename or remove the wp-contet/advanced-cache.php file.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `wp-config.php` file

and check this line

```
define('WP_CACHE', true);
```

If you find then change it to

```
define('WP_CACHE', false);
```

You are done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Doing the following helped me recover my gallery and wp-admin access :

Go to wp-content folder (Get the FTP access to the website)

Check if advanced-cache.php and object-cache.php files are present.

Rename the files to .bak as follows :
 advanced-cache.php.bak and object-cache.php.bak

This error occured due to caching functionality of W3 Total Cache plugin for me.
Hope this helps as it did to me.